# Azure Monitor alert on a custom metric filtered by cloud_RoleInstance

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I'm able to create an alert based on my custom metric. However, i'd like to have several different alerts, for each cloud_RoleInstance I have. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the logs are stored in Azure Log Analytics or Azure Application Insights, then you can use [Custom Log Search alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log#create-a-log-alert-rule-with-the-azure-portal)(in step 5 of this article). Note you need to create one alert as per one cloud_RoleInstance in the query.

Steps as blow:

Step 1:

In azure portal -> Nav to azure monitor -> Alerts -> New alert rule, then in the resource, select the Azure Log Analytics or Azure Application Insights.

Step 2:

Then in Condition, select Add, then select "Custom log search":

[image]

Step 3:

Then in new window, write you query to trigger the alert, remember use where clause to filter the cloud_RoleInstance.

And note that:
change "Based on" from "Number of results" to "Metric measurement",
 and use this query:

```
customMetrics 
| where name == 'MyMetricName' 
| where cloud_RoleInstance == 'MyInstanceName' 
| summarize AggregatedValue = sum(value) by bin(timestamp, 5m)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is almost what i needed. The only thing that I had to do was to change "Based on" from "Number of results" to "Metric measurement" and update my query to produce AggregatedValue:

customMetrics
    | where name == 'MyMetricName'
    | where cloud_RoleInstance == 'MyInstanceName'
    | summarize AggregatedValue = sum(value) by bin(timestamp, 5m)

Can you plz update your answer to include this steps, so it is complete and visible. I will then accept it.

Comment: Well, i think if i mark it as an answer in it's current form, it will be an incomplete one for ppl looking just at it and not into the comments section. That's why i think it's better to add those steps. It will then become a complete answer.

Comment: @DmytroGokun, yeah, I added this information in step 3 :).